# Necessary and Sufficient conditions for vector spaces.

Tags: vector-spaces

My question is very short and simple.

Given a set, V, which contains a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which follows a specific rule -

If I show that the set is closed under both component wise addition of two vectors also in the set, and show that the set is also closed under scalar multiplication, have I proven that the set is a Vector Space?

My immediate thought is, no, due to the fact that if a set doesn't contain the zero vector, then it cant be defined as a vector space.

Do I need to show that the zero vector is a member of the set, or is this assumed by proving the two conditions regarding addition and scalar multiplication above.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: "which follows a specific rule" ... So you are asking about a *very* abstract setup.  In particular just being "closed" under the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication (however the "specific rule" defines them) does not guarantee us that the axioms of the vector space operations are met, e.g. vector addition might not be commutative and scalar multiplication might not be distributive over vector addition.  Your textbook should list the axioms in some consistent way for you.

Comment: @hardmath I can define a rule using the vector above - $6x_1 - 4x_2 + 9x_3 = 0$. It is obvious to me that this is a vector space, but do I have to explicitly show that the zero vector is a member of the set, or would it be sufficient to just just leave it out? P.S Our lecturer has no notes, so knowing his accepted syntax without getting something incorrect first is difficult.

Comment: I think you might be working on an exercise that has as an underlying theme checking when a subset of a vector space is a subspace.  Although this is not explicit in your Question, your mention of $V$ "contains a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which follows a specific rule", taken in combination with the last Comment, suggests that you are working with $V\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, your set contains many points ("vectors"), one of which happens to be $(0,0,0)$.  In this special case we don't have to show all the axioms are satisfied because the vector operations on $V$ are inherited from $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think you are asking.

> I have a vector space $W$ and a subset $V$ of $W$ that I want to show
>   is a subspace. I have proved that $W$ is closed under scalar
>   multiplication and vector addition. I have not proved that $V$
>   contains the $0$ vector. Am I done?

The answer to this question: yes, as long as you can show that $V$ is not empty, because if there is some $v \in V$ then using what you have already proved,
$$
v + (-1)v = 0 \in V.
$$

The problem with the question as you asked it is that you did not tell us that the vectors in $V$ were elements of some larger space - in this case probably $\mathbb{R}^3$. The "rule" is irrelevant in the question, though you need it to write an answer.

Comment: Thank you! The question is -

$V = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 s.t. 6x_1 - 4x_2 + 9x_3 = 0\}$ Is this a vector space. I didnt want someone to just give me an answer so tried to be broader with my question. I was basically asking if I need to show the zero vector follows the rule stated above  aswell as V being closed under addition and scalar multiplication

Comment: In this case yes just show the $0$ vector is there. We appreciate "not just asking for the answer". You didn't do that here. If you ask again here please provide a little more context.

Comment: This Answer validates the concern shown by the Question that merely having a subset (of a vector space) closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication is not enough to conclude it is a subspace, because an empty subset is closed (trivially) under the operations but is *not* a subspace.  The subtle point is that one only needs to show *some* vector exists in the subset to get the conclusion, but often it is as easy to show the zero vector belongs to the subset as to show it is nonempty in any other way.